# how to create last 1 hour's minutes array in descending order using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've a usecase where I need to create an array of minutes with 5 minutes interval in descending order. I need to create that array of last 1 hour. I've tried moment.js. I got the results but not in sorted order.
Here is what I've tried so far.

```js
let dates = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  dates.push(moment(new Date()).subtract(i, 'minutes').format('HH:' + i + ' A'));
  i = i + 4;
}

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the result set I got.

```
15:0 PM
15:5 PM
15:10 PM
15:15 PM
15:20 PM
14:25 PM
14:30 PM
14:35 PM
14:40 PM
14:45 PM
14:50 PM
14:55 PM
```

Results are in unsorted manner. I want them in descending order starting from `15:20` and `14:25` at the end.

One more thing is on how to print the single digit minutes concatenated with `0` at the beginning like, convert `15:5 PM` to `15:05 PM`.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: Why not do `i += 5` in `for()` instead of adding another `i = i + 4` inside the loop?

Comment: It should be ```i+=4```. Because, if we use ```5```, it will return times like this. ```''16:0 PM",
                "15:6 PM",
                "15:12 PM",
                "15:18 PM",
                "15:24 PM",
                "15:30 PM"```

Comment: Oh sorry. Yeah I've tried now. But no use. Output is, ```16:0 PM16:5 PM
16:10 PM
15:15 PM
15:20 PM
15:25 PM
15:30 PM
15:35 PM
15:40 PM
15:45 PM
15:50 PM
15:55 PM```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `HH:mm` format

```js
let dates = [];
let start = moment()
let minutes = start.minute()

start = start.minute(5 * (Math.floor(Math.abs(minutes / 5))))

for (let i = 0; i < 60; i += 5) {
  dates.push(start.subtract(5, 'minutes').format('HH:mm A'));
}

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @User863, it seems to be the answer. But I can't use, ```moment('15:20', 'HH:mm')```. Because, its complete dynamic scenario. If I try to execute the functionality at ```17:06 PM```, it should give the times from ```17th hour```. Not ```15th hour```. Is there any alternative to not use that predefined time?

Comment: Thanks @User863. But it's not giving the 5 minute intervals.

Comment: @Aravind Check now

Comment: 12:08 - this code start from "12:00 PM", my code start from "12:05 PM"

Comment: Yes @Gander. I just cam to know about that. Thanks for sharing the info and the code too.

Comment: Hey @Gander, my server database showing time like, 21:35 and moment.js code returning like 16:05. I think it's +5.30 format of ISO. But I want my moment.js code should return times same as my server db. What should I do now

Comment: If you have another question but not exactly about the same problem, only a new one, you must ask a new question.  These are the rules of this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use isAfter to iterate between two moment.

```js
let from = moment(); // Now
const to = moment().subtract(1, 'hour'); // 1 hour ago

const result = [];

while (from.isAfter(to)) {
    from = from.subtract(5, 'minute');
    result.push(moment(from));
}

console.log(result.map(h => h.format('HH:mm A')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The result will give you an array beginning at the current minute. If you want to get a round 10, 15, 20, etc... you'll have to fetch the last round minute.

Comment: How to get the rounding to 00,05,10 etc.

Comment: let from = moment().subtract((moment().minute() % 5), 'minute'); // Rounded now

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dates = [];
let start = moment().startOf("minute");

start.minute(Math.floor(start.minute() / 5) * 5);

for (let i = 0; i < 60; i += 5) {
  dates.push(start.format("HH:mm A"));
  start.subtract(5, "minutes");
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```